# -ms-filter for gradient in IE8 via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, gradient

I am experimenting on this color control panel where a user can change the look and feel of the page using a slide in control panel. An added complexity is that the slide-in panel is in parent window where as the page that the changes are made to is inside an iframe. I want the changes to take affect as they are made inside the control panel. For this I don't want to use AJAX. For this I have devised an algorithm and it is working fine.

Everything apart an issue with IE8 is working fine. I am using this style definition in css as default when the page is loaded.

(Thanks to Louis Lazaris - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/)

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81a8cb, #4477a1); /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0,#4477a1),color-stop(1, #81a8cb)); /* Safari & Chrome */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#4477a1'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#4477a1')"; /* IE8 */
```

Now this is what I am trying to do in javascript using jQuery ( hex1 and hex2 are two variables containing two hex values for gradient):

```
jQuery('#iframeId').contents().find('.gradient').css(
{
        backgroundImage: '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + hex1 + ',' + hex2 + ')', /* Firefox 3.6 */
        backgroundImage: '-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0,' + hex1 + '),color-stop(1,' + hex2 + '))', /* Safari & Chrome */
        filter:  'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=' + hex1 + ', endColorstr=' + hex2 + ')', /* IE6 & IE7 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='" + hex1 + "', endColorstr='" + hex2 + "')" /* IE8 */
});
```

The code runs fine if I exclude the last condition of -ms-filter (because according to the documentation I read nowhere is it mentioned if this filter is supported by jQuery.css).
For what I see one solution to my problem is to see the name and version of my browser using

```
navigator.userAgent
```

and if it is "Internet Explorer 8.0" I apply single background color.

Now my question is that, is there any other way to go around this and get gradient on IE8 also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an alternative syntax to set CSS with jQuery. try it with following

```
jQuery('#iframeId').contents().find('.gradient').css({
    'background-image': '-moz-linear-gradient(top,' + hex1 + ',' + hex2 + ')', /* Firefox 3.6 */
    'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0,' + hex1 + '),color-stop(1,' + hex2 + '))', /* Safari & Chrome */
    'filter':  'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=' + hex1 + ', endColorstr=' + hex2 + ')', /* IE6 & IE7 */
    '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='" + hex1 + "', endColorstr='" + hex2 + "')" /* IE8 */
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not think it was going to be this simple.

Comment: Doesn't work in ie8, at least not in the dev tools emulator.  It's applying the filter instead of the ms-filter and it's always bright blue.

Comment: Ok, thx... Maybe we can check which browser is visiting your site and use just the right filter.

Comment: Hi algorhythm, been trying all day, this just won't work in ie8.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle But if you remove the line `'filter':  'progid:...` than it works in IE8? The question here was just how to set the '-ms-filter' property with jQuery... Not if 'filter' is the the right property for IE8. Maybe you are right and IE8 has problem with 'filter' in combination with '-ms-filter', but then you have to implement a browser switch and just add the property you need in case of your browser...

Comment: It may be the IE11 emulator.  -ms-filter just does nothing, ever.  
I am hoping for answer in new thread here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926860/jquery-dynamic-background-alpha-in-ie8-ms-filter

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong with your javascript. The object key for `-ms-filter` should be wrapped in double or single brackets or it'll cause a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention about that. This was written only for viewing purposes. In actual for ms-filter I am making a string var before applying css and I am passing the string variable instead of filter settings directly.