# Adding dynamic 'filter' CSS property for IE8 isn't being correctly assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to assign the following CSS property to a DIV in my webpage if the browser displaying the Page is IE8 or IE9 as a work around to the `background-size` property not being supported. I have sniffed the browser and the value for my DIV background image is dynamic, meaning it changes with an event on selection. This is my code

```
// var msieVersion is determined earlier and this is in a nested condition
// to check if the browser is IE

if (msieVersion === 8 || msieVersion === 9) {

 // use jQuery to assign the dynamic CSS property and change the BG image source
 $("#container").css({ "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src +  "',sizingMethod='scale')", "-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src +  "', sizingMethod='scale')"});

}
```

Now when I inspect the element using the IE dev tools the `filter` doesn't seem to be applied. In the format tab the following inline style is listed (the href I have changed but it is correct and working):

```
background-image:url(http://url/img1/1.jpg); FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://url/img1/1.jpg',sizingMethod='scale'); msFilter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://url/img1/1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')
```

Does anyone know how I can assign this property dynamically (with the `src` value changing this cannot be in my style sheet) or can they spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374784/ms-filter-for-gradient-in-ie8-via-jquery)?

Comment: No, but I decided to amend to the head a Style Tag which seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

Appending a Style tag to the page head seems to have resolved this:

```
if (msieVersion === 8 || msieVersion === 9) {
            $('head').append("<style>" +
                "#container {" +
                "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src + "',sizingMethod='scale');" +
                "-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src +  "', sizingMethod='scale')" +
                "}" +
                "</style>");
        }
```